# Displaying a Visio document in a browser other than IE?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-office, visio

On my site, I'm displaying several different types of files in the browser, like images, text files, etc. One of the files I want to display is a Visio document.

To display it on a page, I'm creating an iframe with the source set to the url of the .vsd file. This works fine in IE, but not in any other browser. IE will display the file, but the other browsers just open the download dialog to save the file.

Is there a way to embed a .vsd file in other browsers?

Comment: Export the .vsd as .png or .svg?

Comment: @dtb - I would, but Visio documents often have tabs, which isn't possible with just an image

Comment: .vsd is not a standard web format. I guess even IE users without Visio installed won't be able to view the file. You have to export the .vsd in some way to make it suitable for the web.